# Method inherited by rails model, controller and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, migration, applicationcontroller

How to see the list of all the method provided by ActiveRecord::Base, ApplicationController::Base, and  ActiveRecord::Migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want documents, I recommend apidock.com

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration

On the other hand, you can get all methods in your rails console.
In terminal, go to your rails project folder. running `rails c`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.methods #Get all class methods of ActiveRecord::Base
ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods #Get all instance methods of ActiveRecord::Base
ApplicationController::Base.methods
ApplicationController::Base.instance_methods
ActiveRecord::Migration.methods
ActiveRecord::Migration.instance_methods
```